Does anyone know any stablecoins that has more than 18 decimals?
Does anyone know of any stablecoins that have more than 18 decimals?
I only see fewer than 18 decimals, not more.

There are no popular tokens with more than 18 decimals.
Some bridged stablecoins have exactly 18 decimals, as they are using a generic ERC-20 bridged token contract.

While it's technically possible for a stablecoin to have more than 18 decimals, the standard practice is to use 6 decimals to align with the precision of fiat currencies and to avoid confusion.
So, there don't seem to be any stablecoins in production with more than 6 decimals.
You can also inspect the same in this list of stablecoins, by potentially checking their respective token contracts on etherscan.

Yea, do you know any stablecoin tokens that has more than 18 decimals?
